# Does the order of the columns in an CSV file affect the performance of my neural network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

**It's a classification problem.** 
I have a big dataset (`CSV` file) of flights, where each flight is depicted as a set of variables (`airport_of_departure,  airport_of_arrival, date_of_departure, etc`). Each flight is also characterized by a variable `px_no` that is associated with the number of passengers. 
My neural network aims to predict this variable of the flights, for which this particular variable is unknown. Do you think that the order of the variables (`airport_of_departure, airport_of_arrival, etc`) in my training set affects the outcome? For example, faster/slower learning, better/worse score.

Comment: No order won't effect in this case.

Comment: this question is not really a good fit for StackOverflow, which is for *programming* questions. You probably want to ask at [statistics.se]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for pointing that out, I'm new here.